# batch process for R gui

Tags: r, batch-file

I have created a batch file to launch R scripts in Rterm.exe. This works well for regular weekly tasks. The < PBWeeklyMeetingScriptV3.R > is the R script run by Rterm.

> set R_TERM="C:\Program Files\R\R-2.14.0\bin\x64\Rterm.exe"
>
> %R_TERM% --slave --no-restore --no-save --args 20120401 20110403 01-apr-12 03-apr-11 < PBWeeklyMeetingScriptV3.R > PBWeeklyMeetingScriptV3.batch 2> error.txt

I've tried to modify this to launch the R GUI instead of the background process as I'd like to inspect and potentially manipulate and inspect the data.

If I change my batch file to:

> set R_TERM="C:\Program Files\R\R-2.14.0\bin\x64\Rgui.exe"

the batch file will launch the R GUI but doesn't start the script. Is there a way to launch the script too?

Alternatively is there a way to save/load the work space image to access the variables that are created in the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save and load workspaces by using save.image() and load(). I do this all the time when scripting to pass data sets between two separate script files, tied together using Python or bash. At the end of each R script, just add:

```
save.image("Your_image_name.RData")
```

The image will be the workspace that existed whenever the command was run (so, if it's the last command in the file, it's the workspace right before the exist of the file). We also use this at my job to create "snapshots" of input and output data, so we can reproduce the research later. (We use a simple naming convention to get the time of run, and then label the files with that).

Not sure about launching and then running the GUI with specific scripts in it; I don't think that's a feature you'll find in R, simply because the whole point of running a batch file is usually to avoid the GUI. But hopefully, you can just save the image to disk, and then look at it or pass it to other programs as needed. Hope that helps!

Comment: Great suggestions - this is basically what I wanted to do. Thanks